# How do we delete an object from Priority Queue of user defined data type

Tags: java, priority-queue

```
class Solution{
static class pair implements Comparable<pair> {

    int a, b;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(pair o) {
        return (a-o.a);
    }

    public pair(int a, int b) {

        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;

    }

}
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        PriorityQueue<pair> min = new PriorityQueue<>();
        min.add(new pair(9,0));
        min.add(new pair(2,4));
        pair p=new pair(2, 4);
        min.remove(p);
        System.out.println(min.size());
       
       
       

    }


}
```

how do i delete an pair type element from priority queue. This .remove() method does not seem to work for user defined type classes.

Answer (score 1):

The `remove()` method of the `PriorityQueue` implementation uses an objects `equals()` method to check objects for equality. The default implementation of this method checks for reference equality which isn't given in your situation. You should therefore override the `equals()` method in your `Pair` class like (or similar to) this:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o == this)
        return true;
    if (!(o instanceof Pair)) {
        return false;
    }
    Pair pair = (Pair) o;
    return pair.a == a && pair.b == b;
}
```

For good practice you should override the `hashCode()` method of your `Pair` class as well.